# Multiple small kafka clusters or big shared cluster using AWS MSK

Tags: apache-kafka, publish-subscribe, aws-msk

We are trying to setup Kafka clusters using AWS MSK (Managed streaming for Kafka). We have multiple use cases where we may need >50 topics each having 5-25 partitions and cumulatively ~100 million events being produced in a single day.

Producer count  - ~75

Consumer count - ~150

Taking cost into consideration (infrastructure and monitoring/maintenance)

Is it good to have multiple small clusters or few large shared clusters?

I understand some drawbacks of having large shared clusters where if one cluster goes down, it affects all topics, but maintenance and cost also play a big role where I feel having few large shared clusters might be preferable.

Comment: Given your estimates, there would be a max of 1250 partitions and around 1k events/sec. That doesn't sound too hard for a single cluster to handle. If you go separate clusters you have a big chance that each node won't be doing much and waste a lot of CPU/IO/RAM.

Comment: Thank you @Augusto. Makes sense

Comment: There shouldn't be much maintenence cost when using MSK compared to self hosted

Comment: @OneCricketeer, there may still be maintenance in terms of setting up monitoring and alerts, upgrades, migrations etc. But I agree, with MSK, a lot of cluster maintenance will be take care of